# mysql version 5.7.39 query problem condition with on duplicate

Tags: mysql, if-statement, on-duplicate-key

hi everyone i need help

```
create table wishlist
(
    userID       int                          null,
    wishlistData longtext collate utf8mb4_bin not null,
    constraint userID
        unique (userID),
    constraint whishlist_user_id_fk
        foreign key (userID) references user (id)
);
```

first i did this but it make duplication value in wishlistData

```
$query = "INSERT INTO wishlist (userID, wishlistData)
                VALUES ($userID, JSON_ARRAY('$productId'))
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wishlistData = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(wishlistData, '$[0]', '$productId');";
```

to insert id product to my wishlistData where userID doesn't exist or update if exist using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but here if the id product exist on wishlistData don't update
i code this but doesn't work

```
$query = "INSERT INTO wishlist (userID, wishlistData)
                VALUES ($userID, JSON_ARRAY('$productId'))
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wishlistData = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(wishlistData, '$[0]', IF ((SELECT JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(wishlistData, '$'), 'one', '$productId')  IS Not NULL),wishlistData,'$productId'));";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Recommend using prepared statements, always. What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Can you show some data and expected results. Edit the question with these details.

Comment: please never say "doesn't work"; say what _does_ happen

Comment: The duplicate detection only works on the user id field

Answer (score 0):

first thanks for replaying 
this my wishlist table

```
| userID   | wishlistData   |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | ["90","92"]    |
| 2        | ["65","192"]   |
```

for this code

$query = "INSERT INTO wishlist (userID, wishlistData)
VALUES ($userID, JSON_ARRAY('$productId'))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wishlistData = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(wishlistData, '$[0]', '$productId');";

**Input1** : $productId=100 userID=1 
**Result1 = expected1**:

```
| userID   | wishlistData            |
| -------- | ------------------------|
| 1        | ["100", "90", "92"]     |
| 2        | ["65", "192"]           |
```

**Input2** : $productId=90 userID=1 
**Result2**:

```
| userID   | wishlistData             |
| -------- | ------------------------ |
| 1        | ["90", "100", "90", "92"]|
| 2        | ["65", "192"]            |
```

**expected2**:

```
| userID   | wishlistData          |
| -------- | --------------------- |
| 1        | ["100", "90", "92"]   |
| 2        | ["65", "192"]         |
```

but the second code didn't even make insert

```
$query = "INSERT INTO wishlist (userID, wishlistData)
                VALUES ($userID, JSON_ARRAY('$productId'))
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wishlistData = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(wishlistData, '$[0]', IF ((SELECT JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(wishlistData, '$'), 'one', '$productId')  IS Not NULL),wishlistData,'$productId'));";
```